# Which IO port for coding engines, sensors

Tags: c, io, usb, kernel, hardware

I would like to control some physical engines, switches on/off, lights through a self written C API.

I already have a very general overview of how to achieve this:

Use the kernels abstraction, write a driver on it and use this as control. The driver itself has to manage incoming bytes and interpret them (depends on port).

I personally would prefer to use a USB port because I can use my MacBook to develope.

But I know that the protocol is quite complicated. However here are my specific questions:

1. Which port is good to use (is USB a suitable option?)
2. Could I simply wire a engine to the USBs power cables and connect the data cables to a power swith or do I require an extra board?
3. Are there better docs for OS X, BSD or gnu/Linux?

Bodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control physical engines, you have to add at least a power supply board, there is no way that your USB port drive a DC motor (maybe a LED).

The easiest I/O port on a computer is the LPT (parallel port), but this is a 'very' old thing. I agree that USB port is most convenient but in order to work easily with it I advise you to buy a small card.

This [Usb board](http://www.poscope.com/pokeys56u) (or anything of the same kind) can do the trick.

I hope it could help you,

Comment: sry for the hight latency. Your answer has helped me. I took a look at the board and found out that it requires windows. Also I am excluded from the driver development. I think I want to start easy with just a led connected to the usb port which I can enable and disable.

Comment: Actually for the PoKeys56U there is a C library [here](https://bitbucket.org/mbosnak/pokeyslib) for both UNIX system (Linux & Os X).  
You can also check for an [USB to parallel adapter](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-39488) but in any case, because of the serial communication of USB (Universal **Serial** Bus) you won't be able to just turn ON/OFF an I/O without an adapter.